# Mongoimport on Mac fails with variable in file path

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a json file into mongo. When I import the file with this line, it works:

```
mongoimport -d reps_development -c users --jsonArray --file ~/reps/scripts/mockUserData.json
```

The script uses an environment variables $REPS_ROOT, which is set in my .bash_profile. This line fails:

```
mongoimport -d reps_development -c users --jsonArray --file $REPS_ROOT/scripts/mockUserData.json
```

I set $REPS_ROOT with the following command:

```
export REPS_ROOT="~/reps"
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working? The error I get is:

```
file doesn't exist: ~/reps/scripts/mockUserData.json
```

Comment: Full path works, but I'd really like to know why I can't do this with the relative path. It should work, too, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash expands `$REPS_ROOT` to `~/reps`, which becomes the value. Bash won't expand that value again. If the value of that variable contains a relative path, you need to make sure it is expanded. For example:

```
mongoimport -d reps_development -c users --jsonArray --file $(cd $REPS_ROOT; pwd)/scripts/mockUserData.json
```

If you are on Linux, you can use `$(readlink -f $REPS_ROOT)` instead. Alternatively you can use `$HOME` instead of `~`:

```
export REPS_ROOT="$HOME/reps"
```